# LDA < subroutine x86 assembly emu 6502

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to understand this emu6502 assembly code for my college excersises. The code converts octal numbers to binary numbers.

```
                opt f-g-h+l+o+
                org $1000

start           equ *

                lda <text
                sta $80
                lda >text
                sta $81
                ldy #0
                lda #$a5
                jsr binary

                lda <text
                ldx >text
                jsr $ff80
                brk

binary          sta byte
                ldx #7
bitslp          lda #'0'
                asl byte
                bcc pr
                lda #'1'
pr              sta ($80),y
                iny
                dex
                bpl bitslp
                rts

byte            dta b(0)

                org $2000
text            equ *
                dta b(0),b(0),b(0),b(0)
                dta b(0),b(0),b(0),b(0)
                dta b(10) ; '\n'
                dta b(0)

                org $2E0
                dta a(start)

                end of file
```

I have no idea what <, > symbols stand for in these lines: `lda <text`, `ldx >text`and the purpose of line with `equ *`? I've read many articles on the internet but didn't find anything about greater than, less than signs after lda and asterrisk sign after equ.

I also don't know how to provide input for program. (The number to be converted)

Comment: `<` is the low byte portion of a value, and `>` is the high byte portion of a value.

Comment: `equ` defines some value to symbol (like "symbol = X") (it's directive of assembler, not an instruction of CPU). `*` is special value "current address" where the next byte of machine code will land. The `start` is at address $1000, because right ahead of it the target address is set by `org` directive and no machine code was produced yet.

Comment: text is the address of an 8 byte buffer. The first four instructions store the address of text into location $80 (low part of address) and $81 (high part of address).

Comment: Actually get some docs to your assembler, I'm not 100% sure with that `*`, looks like there are many conventions with 6502 assemblers. Although my answer makes most sense in this case, but if you have documentation to your assembler, trust rather it.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting octal numbers to binary numbers" ? Looking at your code, it simply converts the hexadecimal number 0xA5 into 8 bytes at address @0x2000 representing each bit (0 or 1) in ascii format, from bit7 to bit0. Then it calls an unknown subroutine at address 0xff80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code shown converts the value in A into an ascii-string at $2000

the main part of your code is this

```
binary          sta byte          ; store value to be encoded
                ldx #7            ; loop counter: 1 + 7 times = 8 repeats

; shift A bit by bit, and convert each bit into "0" or "1"

bitslp          lda #'0'          ; default value for bit: not set "0"
                asl byte          ; check next bit (top bit -> carry)
                bcc pr            ; bit clear? keep the "0"
                lda #'1'          ; otherwise use a "1" ...

; store the ascii result at "string pointer" ($80/$81)+y

pr              sta ($80),y       ; ... and store it
                iny               ; y++ (increase string "pointer")

                dex               ; loop counter
                bpl bitslp        ; loop branch
                rts
```

the surrounding code just loads values 
- $2000 into [$80/$81] (the "string"), 
- $0 into Y (which would imo belong into the "binary" subroutine), and 
- $F4 (a sample value) into A to be converted
and finally calls $ff80 (maybe some output function? who knows :-) )